# Sequelize is not updated when I added new column in table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I cannot convince why my sequelize models is not updated when I add new column in table.

I've added new column 'status INTEGER' in my table and updated as follow in Models of my table in sequelize. When I retrieve value from my table, it coming nothing.

[image]

```
            },
            status: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                default: 0
            }
```

Please help me how to solve that issue. And even I've run migration as follow.

```
module.exports = {
    up: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {

        function addDisabledColumn() {
            return migration.addColumn('applications', 'status',
                {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    default: 0
                }
            )
        }

        addDisabledColumn().then(function () {
            done();
        }, function (err) {
            done(err);
        });

    },
    down: function (migration, DataTypes, done) {
        done()
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to resync the table for changes to take effect try `sequalize.sync({force:true})` 
hope it helps :)

Comment: where do I need to put 'sequalize.sync({force:true})' and when do I need to run that script?

Comment: when you first created your tables you must have synced the database. show  me your code, then i will tell you. you can also see in the documentation here under 'Your first model'  http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/getting-started/

Comment: if you are using migrations you should run migrations for changes to take effect  read this post should clear your doubts http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/migrations/ and i recomend you read sequalize documentation

Comment: Yap, I've read that documentation. Even migration is run, new column is added in my table but 'Sequelize' does not recognise that new column even it's in table.

Comment: WARNING: This deletes every record in the table

Comment: I am in same problem @ppshein

Comment: Try other name than "status", thats a tricky name for sequelize to deal with.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

> When I retrieve value from my table, it coming nothing.

The same thing happened to me. I created a migration that added a column to a table. When I would use `.findAll`, `.findOne`, `findAllAndCount`, etc. the column wouldn't be present.

You can get the new column in two ways:

- Add the new column to the model definition. This is needed not only to get the new column with `.find` queries but to also be able to save the column when calling `.create`. If that doesn't work:
- Use `attributes` and explicitly define the new column to be retrieved:

  ```
   const employee = await Employee.findOne({
       where: { id: id },
       attributes: ['id', 'name', 'NEW_COLUMN'],
   });
  ```
- If you're going to query the table in several places, it's best to create an alias with the fields you want to query and use it everywhere you run find queries:

  ```
   const Employee = sequelize.define('employee', {
       id: {
           type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
           primaryKey: true,
           autoIncrement: true
       }, 
       // DONT FORGET TO ADD THE NEW COLUMN TO YOUR MODEL
       NEW_COLUMN: {
           type: DataTypes.STRING,
           allowNull: true,
       }
       // ...
   });

   Employee.basicAttributes = (alias = 'employee') => [
       'id', 
       'name',
       'NEW_COLUMN',
       // ...
   ];

   const employee = await Employee.findOne({
       where: { id: id },
       attributes: Employee.basicAttributes(),
   });
  ```

It's not ideal, but it works, and it doesn't require to run `sequalize.sync({force:true})`.

Answer (score 0):

Now, if you take a look in [API Reference](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html) and scroll to `public async sync` method. You will see `alter` option with `drop` which means we can use `sequalize.sync({alter:true, drop: false})` to update model columns without drop statement.

It should update missing columns on table and would be safe to use on production.

Comment: On the [updated API reference](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize#instance-method-sync) it says: "options.alter Alters tables to fit models. Provide an object for additional configuration. Not recommended for production use. If not further configured deletes data in columns that were removed or had their type changed in the model."